# how to pass a variable using request.setAttribute and send to a another page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts-1

i am using struts1.
my actionclass has code

```
String data = "hi";
request.setAttribut("Data",data);
```

and after that i

```
return "success";
```

My struts.xml have

```
<action path="/Name" type="example.NameAction" >
<forward name="success" path="/displayname.jsp"/>
</action>
```

i used jstl to print the variable in displayname.jsp but the variable is not printed.how to pass a variable to the jsp without using session variable.i want to use request.setAttribute.

Comment: in your displayname.jsp try this : ${requestScope.data}

Comment: i tried but not prints.but i save it to session variable and use ${sessionScope.Data} then it prints.but i don't want to use session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the struts-config.xml action forward redirect=true into redirect=false.then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Thi.it will help you to get variable name.

```
<input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath" value="${filePath}"/> OR
<%String filePath = (String)request.getAttribute("filePath");%>
```